# How to detect aspect ratio of an image in css

Tags: css

A web page contains images that are sometimes in "portrait" mode (height>width) and sometimes in "landscape" mode (width>height).

When displaying these images "full page", I'd like to be able to set height to 100% for portrait images (with the width calculated by the browser so as to respect aspect ratio) and inversely the width to 100% for landscape images.

This is trivial to do in JavaScript, but is there a way/a trick to do it without JavaScript, in CSS only? (It's for an internal website where JavaScript is very likely to be disabled; however the browser used is modern so one could use CSS3 if needed).

---

Alternatively, if that's not possible, the server serving the images could do an evaluation of the size of each image and send "portrait|landscape" as metadata; what would be the most efficient way of doing this (say in PHP?)

Comment: I think you should get this information from backend only. You should not rely on client side for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to set the dimensions you want to restrict the images to on their parent containers and then set the dimensions of the images to `auto` and their max dimensions to 100%.

Here's a quick example with some positioning thrown in to keep the images centred; test it out by adjusting the sizes of the `div` and the image.

```css
div{
    background:black;
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
}
img{
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    left:50%;
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translatex(-50%) translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/nature/3/"></div>
```